# Separate Page Button Ajax Functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, dialog

Im trying to load a page I created using ajax, which loads fine and all. The problem Im having is that the page I load into the dialog has an update button in its form it displays. That button doesn't work since it just redirects to the page Im on without performing the update.

Is there some special way to handle a page loaded in the dialog with the buttons it contains.

This is my ajax request that works and loads the page I wanted.

```
$('[data-label="button_edit"]').bind('click', function(){
        temp = $(this).attr('id');
        contact_id = temp.split('-');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'admin/contacts/add-edit.php?fk_pivot_table=&fk_pivot_id=&contact_id='+ contact_id[1] + '&form_only=true' ,
            success:( function(data) {
                $('#edit_contact_form').html(data).dialog({
                    width: 1500,
                    height: 700
                });
            })
        });
        return false;
    });


<td data-label="form_only" class="-left-side">
                <form action="" method="post" name="form" id="form">
                    <span data-label="footprint_alerts">footprint_alerts</span>
                    <table class="span-17 -form">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th colspan="2">Contact Information</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="-field-label" width="120">Is Default:</td>
                                <td class="-field">
                                    <select size="1" data-field="is_default" name="is_default">
                                        <option value="yes">yes</option>
                                        <option value="no">no</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="-field-label -required">Contact Method:</td>
                                <td class="-field">
                                    <select name="method" data-field="method">
                                        <option value="">-- Select a Contact Method --</option>
                                        <option value="phone">Phone</option>
                                        <option value="email">E-Mail</option>
                                        <option value="form">Form</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="-field-label">Email Address:</td>
                                <td class="-field">
                                    <input type="text" value="" maxlength="128" size="30" name="email" data-field="email" />
                                    <div data-label="email_container"></div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="-field-label">Email Address Alt:</td>
                                <td class="-field">
                                    <input type="text" value="" size="30" name="email_alt" data-field="email_alt" /><br/>
                                    <small class="-lite">This field accepts comma separated e-mail address lists. (ie. john.smith@gmail.com, john.smith@yahoo.com, john.smith@hotmail.com)</small>
                                    <div data-label="email_alt_container"></div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="-field-label">URL:</td>
                                <td class="-field">
                                    <input type="text" value="" maxlength="1024" size="45" name="url" data-field="url" />
                                    <div data-label="url_container"></div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="-field-label">URL Alt:</td>
                                <td class="-field">
                                    <input type="text" value="" maxlength="1024" size="45" name="url_alt" data-field="url_alt" />
                                    <div data-label="url_alt_container"></div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="-field-label">Job Title:</td>
                                <td class="-field">
                                    <input type="text" value="" maxlength="45" size="20" name="job_title" data-field="job_title" />
                                    <div data-label="job_title_container"></div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="-field-label">Company Name:</td>
                                <td class="-field">
                                    <input type="text" value="" maxlength="45" size="25" name="name_company" data-field="name_company" />
                                    <div data-label="name_company_container"></div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="-field-label -required">First Name:</td>
                                <td class="-field">
                                    <input type="text" value="" maxlength="45" size="25" name="name_first" data-field="name_first" />
                                    <div data-label="name_first_container"></div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="-field-label">Middle Name:</td>
                                <td class="-field">
                                    <input type="text" value="" maxlength="45" size="25" name="name_middle" data-field="name_middle" />
                                    <div data-label="name_middle_container"></div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="-field-label -required">Last Name:</td>
                                <td class="-field">
                                    <input type="text" value="" maxlength="45" size="25" name="name_last" data-field="name_last" />
                                    <div data-label="name_last_container"></div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="-field-label">Phone:</td>
                                <td class="-field">
                                    <input type="text" value="" maxlength="20" size="20" name="phone" data-field="phone" />
                                    <div data-label="phone_container"></div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="-field-label">Phone Alt.:</td>
                                <td class="-field">
                                    <input type="text" value="" maxlength="20" size="20" name="phone_alt" data-field="phone_alt" />
                                    <div data-label="phone_alt_container"></div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="-field-label">Address:</td>
                                <td class="-field">
                                    <input type="text" value="" maxlength="45" size="25" name="address" data-field="address" />
                                    <div data-label="address_container"></div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="-field-label">Address 2:</td>
                                <td class="-field">
                                    <input type="text" value="" maxlength="45" size="25" name="address_alt" data-field="address_alt" />
                                    <div data-label="address_alt_container"></div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="-field-label">City:</td>
                                <td class="-field">
                                    <input type="text" value="" maxlength="45" size="25" name="city" data-field="city" />
                                    <div data-label="city_container"></div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="-field-label">Zip:</td>
                                <td class="-field">
                                    <input type="text" value="" maxlength="10" size="10" name="zip" data-field="zip" />
                                    <div data-label="zip_container"></div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="-label">&#160;</td>
                                <td class="-field">
                                    <input type="submit" data-field="button_new" value="Create New" name="action" class="-alt"/>
                                    <input type="submit" value="Update" name="action" data-field="button_update" />
                                    <input type="submit" value="Delete" name="action" data-field="button_delete" />
                                </td>
                             </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </form>
            </td>
```

-Edit- I found a solution to the problem I was having and felt like sharing it

```
$('[data-label="button_edit"]').bind('click', function(){           
        temp = $(this).attr('id');
        contact_id = temp.split('-');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'admin/contacts/add-edit.php?fk_pivot_table=&fk_pivot_id=&contact_id='+ contact_id[1] + '&form_only=true' ,
            success:( function(data) {
                contactForm = $('#edit_contact_form_container').html(data);
                $('#contact_form').find('[data-field="button_update"]').css('visibility','hidden');
                $('#contact_form').bind('submit', function(){
                    $.post('admin/contacts/add-edit.php?fk_pivot_table=&fk_pivot_id=&contact_id='+ contact_id[1] + '&form_only=true&action=Update Contact',$('#contact_form').serialize());
                    contactForm.dialog('close');
                });
                contactForm.dialog({
                    width: 700,
                    height: 700,
                    title: 'Edit Contact Information',
                    buttons: {
                        "Go To Contacts Page": function(){
                            location.href='admin/contacts/add-edit.php?fk_pivot_table=&fk_pivot_id=&contact_id=' + contact_id[1];
                        },
                        "Update Contact": function(){
                            $.post('admin/contacts/add-edit.php?fk_pivot_table=&fk_pivot_id=&contact_id='+ contact_id[1] + '&form_only=true&action=Update Contact',$('#contact_form').serialize());
                            contactForm.dialog('close');
                            window.location.reload();
                        }
                    }
                });
            })
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: not clear what behavior you are looking for from form buttons.  AJAX?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. Basically what I have working now is a form appearing inside a dialog box that is obtained from a different php page. The problem is the form that appears inside the dialog box has buttons from the other page, though when I click on one of those buttons it doesn't perform any type of functionality. Keep in mind that those buttons work on the separate php page. So Im not sure how I can make that button work on the current page Im on.

Comment: I don't see any buttons in the code you provided. Can you please post all needed code to answer your questions.

Comment: @Paul yeah sure thing give me a sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on info that buttons work on standalone page. If they have script on standalone, the ready event has already occured on main page where dialog is, so if script is not loading after the new html it will fire prematurely.

You can call the same script within the same ajax success where you create dialog ( after you load new html in dialog) or make sure the script tag on loaded page is afer the html it refers to

Comment: Yeah your right Im going to have to bind the forms submit and stop it from firing after it loads